# IBM Watson Discovery API query

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I am trying to use  watson discovery api and makes request like this:

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1
/environments/6da44f3d-678f-476a-ae8b-cf69327fcf93
/collections/f9c98c9e-be05-4a00-bc93-7159f5441251/query
?version=2016-11-07
&query=text:Ukraine,taxonomy:(label:technology,score>0.8)
&count=10
&offset=
&aggregation=
&filter=
&return=
```

First item in response has taxonomy like this:

```
"taxonomy": [
    {
      "score": "0.976715",
      "label": "/law, govt and politics/armed forces/army"
    },
    {
      "confident": "no",
      "score": "0.499065",
      "label": "/technology and computing/computer certification"
    },
    {
      "confident": "no",
      "score": "0.496026",
      "label": "/law, govt and politics/legal issues/human rights"
    }
  ]`
```

Taxonomy's item labeled "technology" has score 0.499065 but I need items which has label with word "technology" AND score >0.8 (not OR).
How do I change my request to get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Impossible? Sure?

Comment: this may help someone looking for it.. http://blog.staginginstance.com/using-ibm-watsons-discovery-service-get-fresh-content/

Answer (score 1):

Lets step back first. The goal of this query is to find documets where the text references 'Ukraine' and then filter all results so that they taxonomy technology is there and has a score over 0.8

I can't test this myself without access to your environment but it should be

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1
/environments/6da44f3d-678f-476a-ae8b-cf69327fcf93
/collections/f9c98c9e-be05-4a00-bc93-7159f5441251/query
?version=2016-11-07
&query=text:Ukraine
&count=10
&offset=
&aggregation=
&filter=taxonomy:(label:technology,score>0.8)
&return=
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. If set query to "taxonomy:(label:technology,score>0.8)" without any filters - works, but adding any additional filter breaks the answer.